# How to tell EclipseLink to use an XmlAdapter for a certain type globally?

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink

I want to persist an object tree to XML using EclipseLink MOXy. But I want all fields of type `double` to be written using a custom `DoubleAdapter`. I know that I can do that with package based annotation like

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({ @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = double.class, value = DoubleAdapter.class) })
package example;
```

The problem is, that I have to add this to every package, which seems very stupid.

I even tried it using an `bindings.xml` file, but again it is limited to one package.

Is there a way to configure the JAXBContext such that it always uses the `DoubleAdapter` when it encounters an object of type `double`?

**Update**

I tried using the following `bindings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" package-name="java.lang">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Double">
            <xml-java-type-adapter value="moxy.DoubleAdapter" />
            <java-attributes />
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

But then the creation of the JaxbContext results in a NullPointerException. Why?

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "bindings.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { Foo.class }, props);
```

Adding a global XmlAdapter at class level via XML metadata this way works for my own classes, but it somehow does not work for `Double`?

Ok, I debugged through the process and found that `java.lang.Double` is listed in the XMLToJavaTypeMap. This leads to `typeInfoMap` not containing a `TypeInfo`, which leads to the NPE in `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.XMLProcessor.processXML()`. So, type infos are not generated for Java built in types. Why?

Btw, if I want the adapter to be used for `double` and `Double`, I have to set

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({ 
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = double.class, value = DoubleAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = Double.class, value = DoubleAdapter.class) 
})
package example;
```

But how do I refer to a primitive type like `double` in the XML bindings file?

**Update 2**

Specifying bindings on package level as XML like (note the primitive `double`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" package-name="foo">
   <xml-java-type-adapters>
      <xml-java-type-adapter value="foo.DoubleAdapter" type="double"/>
      <xml-java-type-adapter value="foo.DoubleAdapter" type="java.lang.Double"/>
   </xml-java-type-adapters>
</xml-bindings>
```

results in

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXB
Exception: 
Exception Description: An invalid XmlJavaTypeAdapter [foo.DoubleAdapter] was specified for package [foo]. Possible causes are an incorrect adapter class name or
 the wrong loader has been set.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50065] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: An invalid XmlJavaTypeAdapter [foo.DoubleAdapter] was specified for package [foo]. Possible causes are an incorrect adapter class name or
 the wrong loader has been set.]
```

Using package level annotation works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The largest scope you can register an `XmlAdapter` for in EclipseLink MOXy or any JAXB (JSR-222) implementation is the package level.

**For More Information**

You can read more about JAXB and package level adapters on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, this is a limitation of JAXB if I get you right? If I want to use an `XmlAdadpter` globally on a class I wrote myself, I can just add `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` at class level. But is there no way to do this for a foreign class? Do I really have to generate `package-info.java`s with ant or generate a `eclipse-oxm.xml` for each package to achieve this behavior?

Comment: OK, I tried applying meta data to `java.lang.Double` via a `bindings.xml` file but this results i a NullPointerException when creating the JAXB context.

Comment: @Adam - Can you post what you tried and the resulting exception?

Comment: I updated the question. This might be a corner case because doubles are already handled by EclipseLink. What do I need it for? I want to define my own output format for numbers and I want to allow math expressions like 2*pi+log(8) to be parsed as double.